# AnimatedSwitcher doesn't switch between Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Goal: Switching between two very simple Widgets containing simple Text with the help of AnimatedSwitcher.

Below is my code:

[image: mainPage]

[image: First Widget i want to animate to]

[image: Second Widget i want to animate to]

Whenever i press the button which should trigger the animation from the first widget to the second widget, nothing happens.
Both prints appear in the console : 'before' and 'after'.

Is this some kind of bug or why isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both of your widgets are pretty much the same, flutter needs some kind of differentiation between them. The most straight forward approach would be using a UniqKey() on both of your containers.

```
...
Container(key: UniqKey(), ...),
```

Comment: I added a Unique Key to each of the Containers, but it didn't help. Strange.

Comment: I didn't pay attention to the main page screenshot. Try to move the definitions of the list and _animatedWidget out of the build method.

Comment: Thanks! It did work! Btw. The Unique Key is not necessary. Taking the definitions out of the build method was enough.

Comment: The setState method is causing a widget rebuild. Therefore you are redefining the _animatedWidget on each build